# Button which opens a new Tk() window on clicking it in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So I am trying to make a button which opens a new Tk() window when clicked on it. It is opening the window on clicking the button but its not showing the image I have inserted. What should I do?

Here is my code

```
def clothing():
    harsh = Tk()
    harsh.geometry("434x366")
    harsh.title("Clothing Accessories")
    image = Image.open("Eshop_Mobile - Copy.jpg")
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    pic_label = Label(image = photo)
    pic_label.pack()    
    harsh.mainloop()
win = Tk()
win.title("Eshop App - Best Online Shopping System")
Photo = PhotoImage(file = "Eshop1.png")
pic_label = Label(image = Photo)
pic_label.pack()
b0 = Button(win,text = 'Clothing Acc',command = clothing )
b0.place(x = 10, y = 400)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Avoid using multiple instances of `Tk()`.  Change `Tk()` to `Toplevel()` inside `clothing()` and remove the line `harsh.mainloop()`.  Also you need to keep the reference of `photo` by adding `pic_label.image = photo`.

Comment: after doing the changes @acw1668 said, try this. When ur using images inside of a function u might need to make it a `global` variable just try saying `global photo,pic_label` on top of clothing function

Answer (score 0):

## Toplevel Function

The `Toplevel` function is made for creating new windows from a parent window.
You should not use `Tk()` more than once as it can result in breaking the main parent loop

Refer to this link if you want to know more on `Toplevel()`
[python-tkinter-toplevel](https://www.javatpoint.com/python-tkinter-toplevel)

Here is a tutorial on "Creating a new window tkinter" from 2:35:41 to 2:44:20
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXPyB4XeYLA

Try this

```
def clothing():
    harsh = Toplevel()
    .
    harsh.mainloop()
win = Tk()
.
win.mainloop()
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Avoid calling `mainloop()` more than once.